# Problem with adding a new field to the res partner model

Tags: view, field, odoo

I try to add a radio button to my vendor view, after installing my module there are no changes in my view.
I wish you can help me

1/ my file.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, models, api


class Vendor(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    type = fields.selection([('internal', 'Internal'), ('external', 'External')], 'Type')
```

2/ My Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <field name="payment_term_id" position="after">
                    <field name="type" widget="radio"/>
                </field>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two possibility:

1. If you want to see field on `res.partner` form view, then change field name and upgrade `res.partner` form view.

   `type` field is already introduce by Odoo base core module.

   In these case, you can change your field from `type` to `partner_type`. And same with xml side.
2. If you want to see field on `sale.order` form view, then inherit `sale.order` object and upgrade it.

Afterwards, Upgrade your module and check output.

Comment: Yes, type already exists in res partner this is why i dont see changes in my view. Now i changed the name of my field and below is the error message which is displayed:        "The partner_type field does not exist". I have tried to restart my server but it doesn't work

Comment: @meriemman You haven't read answer carefully. In which form, do you want to display field ?

Comment: sorry,i want to display the field in the res.partner.form

Comment: Then you have to change xml inherit ID, model, name from sale.order to res.partner and fine partner base xml side and inherit that form view.

Answer (score 0):

1/ remove the file of res.partner object from init file

2/ uninstall your module

3/ add the file of res.partner object to init file again

4/ restart the server and reinstall your module